# I'm searching for Ricochet Robots, travel version

Tags: identify-this-game, puzzles

Years ago I played a game similar to Ricochet Robots, but a single player travel version.

This game has a small board (something like 5x5 tiles) and several robot pieces.
It includes cards with puzzle configurations (about 100 I remember) that the player should solve.

The mechanics of the game are similar to Ricochet Robots (or a Zelda ice and blocks puzzle), where you move a Robot in one direction until it collides with another element. The objective is to get the robot to a selected position on the board.

I don't remember the name nor the company that made this game but I want to try it again. Does anyone know it?

Comment: I think I've played it or something quite like it... I'll rack my brains!

Comment: I'll trying racking my brains for years. ...umm...
note: it has more than 5 years.

Comment: The problem is I used to own this when I lived in Canada (someone got it me as a present), but I have since moved to the UK and left it thousands of miles behind me.  Such a game definitely does, or did, exist though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the game I think I was thinking of: **LUNAR LOCKOUT**

http://www.funagain.com/control/product?product_id=010971&reviews_show_all=Y

[image]

Here's how one of the reviews describes it:

> This is a great little solitaire game. It's quite similar to Ricochet
>   Robot in theme, but there are some important differences. There are no
>   walls--not even around the edges. You must get your man to the center
>   solely by bouncing him off robots. The goal-spot is always the red
>   square in the center. Instead of random board and piece placement, you
>   must solve puzzles as provided on cards. If you think these
>   differences would make it more simple than Ricochet Robot, then you're
>   in for a big surprise. The puzzles, especially at the top levels, are
>   tear-your-hair-out difficult. Solutions are thankfully provided on the
>   backs of the cards, but that's cheating. The components are very high
>   quality. The robots all have their own 'look' beyond being different
>   colors. The base of the board slides out nicely, has storage space for
>   the robots and cards, and snaps together snugly. My only complaint is
>   that I'd like to see an expansion set soon with new puzzles to solve.